# Solving a nonlinear, first order ODE with a trig function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have an equation of the form,

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = A(x) + B(x) \sin^2(y)$$

How would I go about solving this? Obviously were $A(x) = 0$ then this would be separable and all would be OK, however the presence of the $A(x)$ term is confusing me.

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Do you have a specific equation in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide both sides by $\sin^2(y)$ to get

$$\csc^2(y)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=A(x)\csc^2(y)+B(x)$$

Apply a Pythagorean identity:

$$\csc^2(y)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=A(x)\cot^2(y)+A(x)+B(x)$$

Let $u=\cot(y)$ to get

$$-\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}=A(x)u^2+A(x)+B(x)$$

which is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: But this is contingent on us knowing a particular solution to $u(x)$, correct? How would one obtain that?

Comment: This shows that the problem is equivalent to another problem which is not solvable in general. Depending on $A$ and $B$, this may be solvable though.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect a closed-form solution for general $A(x)$ and $B(x)$.  Even for $A(x)=x$ and $B(x)=1$, or $A(x)=1$ and $B(x)=x$, Maple finds no closed-form solution.  Of course numerical or series solutions are available.

Comment: OK thank you. Could you point me in the direction of how a series solution would work?

Comment: Write $y(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$ (as many terms as you like),
take series of left and right sides of the equation, and compare coefficients of each power of $x$.  Solve the resulting equations to get $a_1, \ldots, a_N$ as functions of $a_0 = y(0)$.

Comment: Thus if $A(x) = x$ and $B(x)=1$, you get $$a_1 + 2 a_2 x +  \ldots =  \sin^2(a_0) + (1 + 2 \sin(a_0) \cos(a_0) a_1) x + \ldots$$ so $a_1 = \sin^2(a_0)$,
$a_2 = 1/2 +  \sin^3(a_0) \cos(a_0)$, etc.

Comment: You probably want to go through my answer and convert the problem into a second order linear equation if you want to apply Frobenius.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it when $A(x)=B(x)$, then
$$\frac{dy}{1+\sin^2 y}=A(x) dx \implies \int\frac{dy}{1+\sin^2y}=\int A(x) dx+C$$
$$\implies \int \frac{du}{1+2u^2}=\int A(x) dx +C \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1} u\sqrt{2}, u=\tan y.$$
$$y(x)=\tan^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan\left[ \sqrt{2}\left( \int A(x) dx+C \right)\right]\right\}$$